# How to init a repository with a public github account and request an other premium account to host it on their github as a private repo?

Tags: git, github, repository, push

Hi I was given by an organization an environment to work on, and I figured out one of its repos has to be versioned, but it contains private things.

Having only a free plan Github account, I then can't host it on my own Github, and need it to be pushed somewhere private, which only possibility is the organization Github (premium account).

How can I init the repo with my account (without asking them their Github credentials), and send some "pull request" to them? (quotation marks because a pull request is normally done to suggest updates to an existing repo, whereas here it'd be pushed online for the first time.)

regards

Comment: Go into the repository settings and transfer ownership to them. They can then make it private. I don't think they can make it private while you are still the owner.

Answer (score 0):

[Github recently announced](https://github.blog/2019-01-07-new-year-new-github/) that all users (even free plan ones) can create private repositories.

If you visit https://github.com/new, you'll notice a new `Private` option for your new repository:

[image: new private repo option]

You can create your private repo, add the organization's members as Contributors, and then submit your Pull Request to them.